# Failing Create Directory Oracle/JDBC

Tags: java, database, oracle

I am running CREATE DIRECTORY command from JDBC.

`CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY a_dir AS '/usr/bin/afile_dir';`

I am getting I am getting SQL Error: `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.`

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

To create directory you should must have CREATE ANY DIRECTORY system privilege

You must have CREATE ANY DIRECTORY system privilege to create directories. You should use below code.

```
SQL> GRANT CREATE ANY DIRECTORY TO abc;

Grant succeeded
```

then perform following command

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY bfile_dir AS '/usr/bin/bfile_dir';
```

Comment: I am getting SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges @Maheshwar

Comment: Ok but is there any other way to do that without those rights ? @Maheshwar